# How can i access data from an Axios request

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm using React JS with Redux and have a little problem retrieving data from a request with Axios..
Here is my Axios request :

```js
import Axios from 'axios';

class UsersApi {
  static getAllUsers() {
    return Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/user').then(response => {
      return response;
    });
  }
}

export default UsersApi;
```

And this is where i want to use my data :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class UserList extends Component {

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.users);
    return(
      <ul>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

This is the action :

```js
import UsersApi from '../api/UsersApi';

export function loadUsers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return UsersApi.getAllUsers().then(users => {
      dispatch(loadUsersSuccess(users));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}

export function loadUsersSuccess(users) {
  return {type: 'LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS', users};
}
```

And this is my reducer :

```js
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function usersReducer(state = initialState.users, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS":
      return action.users
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And this is what i have with console.log : [Result console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zai1Q.png)
When i try to display the password of the first user i put console.log(this.props.users.data["0"].pwd) but this is not working..

If I try to return response.data["0"].pwd in the request I can have the password with console.log(this.props.users).

But the problem is that i want the data of every User..

I need some help. :)

Comment: are you adding your users to your state?

Comment: @BravoZulu no i'm not

Comment: then you are not going to be able to access it through the props in your UserList..

Comment: I see a problem in your axios request. You are returning the response and then storing the response in your state. Be sure to access the data property of response. Example: `.then(response => response.data);`. This way you have the data that came from your api.

Comment: what do you mean by console.log(this.props.users.data["0"].pwd)  is not working ?
any error in console?
you have an arrary of users access in your component already , you logged it successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to add your users to your state. I see you are using redux, so you should dispatch an action after receiving your users and let your reducers handle it:

```
Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/user').then(response => {
  dispatch(usersLoaded(response.data));
});
```

You should have an action called `usersLoaded` and a reducer that handles it:

```
const usersLoaded = users => ({ type: 'USERS_LOADED', payload: users });

const users = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'USERS_LOADED':
       return action.payload;
    default:
       return state;
  }
}
```

This way you'll be able to access your users in your `UserList` component

Comment: Sorry i forgot to post my Actions and my reducer, i just edited!

Comment: You are not dispatching an action when you recieve your users, that's what you are missing

Comment: you need to change your `.then` in your `Axios.get` because you are returning a response, and you need to return `response.data`. Otherwise, when you dispatch `loadUsersSuccess` you are not getting an array, but an object.

Comment: So? that's what you want. Each object in the array is a user

Comment: Yes but for example if i want the pwd of the first user i have tu put console.log(this.props.users["0"].pwd) but its not working.. 
Look here :http://imgur.com/a/yehSg

Comment: and if i only put this: console.log(this.props.users["0"]), i have this : http://imgur.com/a/YJRia

Comment: I think that's because the call is async. On the first render, you don't have users defined, so you won't be able to access `.pwd` of undefined

Comment: if you do `console.log(this.props.users)` you'll see that first there's an empty array (the `initialState` of your users) and after the async ends, you'll get your users there

Comment: Yes i have an empty array first, so How do I resolve the problem?

Comment: It's not a problem, that's how it works. Before rendering anything, check if the array has a value. `render() { if(!this.props.users.length) return <div> Loading users</div>; }`. And after that, you can render everything else

Answer (score 0):

As a proper redux way to do things, right inside the `then` on your `get` call you need to fire an action to `SET_USERS` in which you will use your reducer to replace your state with your new users coming back from the api.